# Hamilton's principle for fields

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, classical-field-theory

According to [Goldstein](https://www.amazon.com.br/Classical-Mechanics-3rd-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0201657023), [Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle) can be summerized as follows:

> The motion of the system from time $t_{1}$ to time $t_{2}$ is such that the line integral (called the action or the action integral):
> $$I := \int_{t_{1}}^{t_{2}}Ldt $$
> where $L=T-V$, has a stationary value for the actual path of the motion.

Putting in another words, a physical dynamical system evolves in such a way that its path is a stationary point of $I$.

The above statement involves words like *motion* and *path*, which are strongly related to mechanical systems as studied in classical mechanics. However, an analogous version of Hamilton's principle also holds for *fields*, specially those defined on a spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{d,1}$.

**Question:** What is the precise (analogous) statement for fields in classical field theory?

Comment: It seems like you already know the principle of stationary action for fields, so it would help if you said why that's not enough for you. Also, the version you quote is not very precise - it's missing the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Javier, in classical mechanics, the motion is described by its generalized coordinates $q_{1},...,q_{N}$ which are functions of time. These are parametrized curves in the configuration space, so if we fix the endpoints $t_{1},t_{2}$ the system undergoes a trajectory in the configuration space which is a stationary point of $S$.  This seems not to be the right "mechanics" for the description of fields: for starters, now the coordinates (say, positions) are also parameters (at least for relativistic fields) and the configuration space is composed by $N$ fields. (continues)

Comment: Fields propagate...so although the idea might remain the same (the path in the configuration space **of fields** is a stationary point of the action), what is the interpretation of this path, now? Fields usually propagate, so would it be correct to say that the propagation of the fields from time $t_{1}$ to $t_{2}$ inside a region $\Omega$ of the space is such that ithe associated path in the configuration space is a stationary point of $S$? I mean, what is the right interpretation for a path in the configuration space for fields, that is the key point!

Comment: Also, I don't know if I understand the point you raised about boundary conditions. Can you elaborate?